# Display user names in Select

Tags: ember.js

I have a routes model that gets a companies list of employees. The Employee model is asociated  with the User model, which has the employees first and last name. To display the list employee names I do this in the model and template:

```
return this.modelFor('management').get('employees');

{{#each}}
    {{render "employee" user}}
{{/each}}
```

Where user is the user Id, and the employee template simply displays {{fullName}}.

I was wondering how I could bind the full name to a drop down list, where the values would come from Employee id, (that works), but the full name which comes from the associated User would be displayed in the Select box.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Ember select view:

```
{{view Ember.Select
     content=controller.employees
     optionLabelPath="content.user.displayName"
     optionValuePath="content.employeeId"
     value=selectedEmployee
}}
```

`optionLabelPath` sets the label(display) for each option, and `optionValuePath` sets what value of the selected option will be set to the `value` property.

[JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dajikutotefu/1/edit)